# Conditional navigation between multiple web forms in sequence?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a web site (ASP.NET, no MVC) with multiple web forms for filling out data for customers wizardry style.

Let's say I have `Form1, Form2, Form3, Form4, Form5, Form6, form7`
All but first and last forms have a Next and Previous button with simple code for redirect, for example on Form4

```
btnNext_Click -> Response.Redirect("Form5.aspx");
btnPrevious_Click -> Response.Redirect("Form3.aspx");
```

Works fine but on the first form there's a radiobutton list and depending on what's been selected some forms should be skipped so I can't hard code the navigation anymore. I.e.
if radiobutton 1 is selected then the wizard would be

```
Form1 -> Form2 -> Form6 -> Form7
```

if radiobutton 2 is selected then the wizard would be

```
Form2- > Form3 -> Form7
```

Radiobutton list is customer type and will be saved to the DB with the rest of the data.

Not looking for complete code sample but more so how you would go on about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate class with Switch .. Case code to handle the appropriate code branching.

```
class OpenWebForm
{
    protected void SelectForm(string option)
    {
        switch (option)
        {
            case "1":

                break;

            case "2":

                break:

        }

    }
}
```

Create an instance of this class and pass the selected option as parameter. In your Web Form's Next Button Click, call the method of this class.

Answer (score 2):

Use [wizard control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15804/ASP-NET-2-0-Wizard-Control), it provide built in next previous functionality